# CodeIgniter database error when opening the website

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

The website works fine for a while but in a few days returns this error :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local
>   MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 202
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Login.php Line: 8
>   Function: database
>
> File: /var/www/html/index.php Line: 289 Function: require_once
>
> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php
>
> Line Number: 500

Help will be appreciated

Thanks

Nipun

Comment: What's the code for line 8 in your login.php?

Comment: Is the database still running and accepting new connections when this error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Three things possible. Your database has been shut down (or it has died). You have not setup database to use a unix socket when both client and server are on the same machine. Or socket is not readable and writable by web user.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is being thrown by mysqli driver. I would recommend that you use PDO driver to connect to the Database.It's simpler and a bit universal (You don't need to change Database settings once you change the DB)

Answer (score 0):

you need confirm the database config file:application/config/database.php ensure the confirm item is correct

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check your mysql server connectivity
2. If you run the app using your pc name i.e. 
   sahil-pc/recruitement or http://85.215.963.104:81/recruitement
   you need to define it in index.php of root.
3. please check the permission of your db socket if you are using linux you need to make it in read and write mod.

note: ip details are fake don't try it